# Erro ao inicializar aplicação com Spring Boot

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, spring-boot

Estou criando uma aplicação utilizando Spring Boot com JPA.
Quando vou subir a aplicação, é lançado a seguinte mensagem:

> Description:
>   Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
>   Action:
>   If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. >If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may >need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Ok, procurei no google e achei um tópico do próprio StackOverFlow [(link da resposta aqui)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type), falando para configurar o `application.properties` qual `DataSource` será utilizado. Porém, não quero fazer diretamente nesse arquivo, pois quero setar o `DataSource` diretamente na aplicação.

Minha classe:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.sys.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        DataSource ds = dataSource();

        ConnectionManager.getInstance().setDataSource(ds);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "br.com.sys.configuration.LowercaseNamingStrategy");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(ds);
        em.setPackagesToScan("br.com.sys.model");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("postgres");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

A anotação `@Configuration` não deveria estar "chamando" o SpringBoot para essa classe para poder fazer a configuração do `DataSource`?
O jeito que estou fazendo é correto, ou deveria usar o application.properties?

Alguém????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema se dava porque a minha classe main, que contém o BootApplication, por um descuido meu, não estava no pacote root do projeto. Sendo assim, ele não conseguia ler a minha classe de configuração postada acima.
Após mover minha classe main para o pacote root, tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acho que está quase tudo correto, porém sempre que eu quero aplicar configurações do hibernate eu chamo diretamente o método setHibernateProperties na criação do factory. Segue meu exemplo:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.websystique.spring.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}
```

Comment: Cara, desculpe, acabei esquecendo de responder a minha própria pergunta. O problema se data porque a minha classe main, que contém o BootApplication, por um descuido meu, não estava no pacote root do projeto. Sendo assim, ele não conseguia ler a minha classe de configuração postada acima. Mas agradeço por sua resposta.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar, poderia responder sua pergunta e marcá-la como correta? Dessa forma outras pessoas saberão que já foi solucionado e como foi que tu resolveu  o problema

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Feito. Obrigado!